# grouped bar chart in R- 4 groups, 3 subgroups

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to plot this data in R

```
group1(extremely obese=1.3, obese=8.6, overweight=10.9)

group2(extremely obese=8.6, obese=19.5, overweight=15.7)

group3(extremely obese  =7.6, obese =21.9, overweight 1=7)

group4(extremely obese=4.4, obese=14.7, overweight=13.8)
```

I have tried many codes suggested on tutorials but I keep running into problem with red scripts. 
often saying "error in data frame", error in bar chart formula, subject not found.

I want the data to be in a grouped bar chart where the x axis have the groups 1-4 with subgroups as (extremely obese, obese, overweight), and the y axis as the corresponding numbers which represents a percentage.

How can I get this to display?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Solving this question will take a few steps. I suggest you 1) learn how to create a data frame  https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r/chapter-5-data-frames?ex=4     2) Use it to make a bar chart using the tutorial here:  https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2/   or  http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/#bar-graphs  or http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization#barplot-with-multiple-groups

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with [Jon Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6851825/jon-spring) that this question is far too broad, I felt challenged to take the data in the given format and to create the desired chart.

The task requires to read in the data, reshape from wide to long format and to create the plot:

```
# dataset as posted by the OP
txt <- "
group1(extremely obese=1.3, obese=8.6, overweight=10.9)

group2(extremely obese=8.6, obese=19.5, overweight=15.7)

group3(extremely obese  =7.6, obese =21.9, overweight =17)

group4(extremely obese=4.4, obese=14.7, overweight=13.8)
"

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

txt %>% 
  # turn special characters into column separators
  gsub("[(=)]", ",", .) %>% 
  # read 
  fread(., blank.lines.skip = TRUE) %>%
  # reshape from wide to long format with two value columns
  .[, melt(.SD, "V1", list(c("V2", "V4", "V6"), c("V3", "V5", "V7")),
           value.name = c("subgroup", "percent"))] %>% 
  # rename first column
  .[, setnames(.SD, "V1", "group")] %>% 
  # create chart
  ggplot() +
  aes(group, percent, fill = subgroup) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]